# How to text to speech (pdf, docx) documents in lubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, pdf, text-to-speech

Hello I want text to speech application that works with PDF and other files. Is there any application that does this is Lubuntu? Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Festival TTS** or **Free TTS**.

You can refer this links : http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php & http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/